# Can't find variable:dispatch

Tags: react-native, reducers

I am running my react-native app but getting error such as: **Can't find variable : dispatch**. I am using reducer for managing different states in this app ! Any help will be appreciated!

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';
import {Button, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const reducer = (state, action) => {

    switch (action.colorToChange) {
        case 'red':
            return {...state, red: state.red + action.amount};
        case 'green':
            return {...state, green: state.green + action.amount};
        case 'blue':
            return {...state, blue: state.blue + action.amount};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const HomeScreen = () => {
    const [state, action] = useReducer(reducer, {red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0});
    const {red, green, blue} = state;

    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Red"  onPress=() => {dispatch({colorToChange: 'red', amount: 1})}/>
            <Button title="Green" onPress={() => dispatch({colorToChange: 'green', amount: 1})}/>
            <Button title="Blue"  onPress={() => dispatch({colorToChange: 'blue', amount: 1})}/>

            <Text>Red Color:{red}</Text>
            <Text>Green Color:{green}</Text>
            <Text>Blue Color:{blue}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: Please mark the answer if any of the provided answers resolved the issue for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

useReducer returns the dispatch as the second element of the destructured array in your case it's named action, you should change your use reducer line to

```
 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0});
```

after this you will be able to use dispatch.. you can use it now by invoking action().. but the naming seems quite wrong

Answer (score 1):

The second variable is the dispatch from `useReducer`, so it should be as

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0});
```